# Using PHP exec() send back information in steps

Tags: php, ajax, bash, composer-php, command-line-interface

I am using PHP `exec()` to install **Composer** dependencies:

`exec('php composer.phar install -d ' . dirname(__DIR__), $out);`

This is triggered via an ajax post request. Everything works fine and the return from `exec()` is printed to the screen.

`exit(json_encode($out));`

However, what I am after is a way to periodically send data back to the ajax callback so I can render each bit of information rather than render the whole block at once.

Not sure if this is possible though.

I should mention that the servers where this would be ran would not have anything like NodeJS and would very likely be shared hosting.

Comment: I think `WebSocket`s might help.

Comment: I would prefer not to use websockets as I need to support some older browsers (IE)

Comment: How? The underlying problem is that Carl is creating a data stream but is then transferring it as a datagram.

Comment: After having open connection he could push chunks of data to the other side. To implement it with Ajax only, you will need to build a state machine, but it could easily get complicated.

Comment: There are solutions for websockets on IE6+ using flash https://github.com/arahaya/FlashSocket

Comment: Use [socket.io](http://socket.io)

Comment: I've updated the question at the bottom with more information regarding my needs. I can't use anything like NodeJS or NPM

Comment: What you are doing requires the source code folder being writable by the webserver. This is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Security issues of exec'ing on-demand aside, if you are able to write/log the status of the output to a file, you can write a simple AJAX poller (since you prefer not to use WebSockets).

In your exec, try:

**add-task.php**

```
$jobId = uniqid();
$outfile = $jobId . "-results.txt";
exec('php composer.phar install -d ' . dirname(__DIR__) . " > $outfile &", $out);
$result = array("jobId" => $jobId);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Ok, now send that `$jobId` down to the client, so that they can poll for updates. I'm using a variation of a concept project on github: https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling

**server.php**

```
$jobid = isset($_GET['jobid']) ? $_GET['jobid'] : null;
$outputfile = $jobid . "-results.txt";
$lastTimestamp = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? (int)$_GET['timestamp'] : null;

// get timestamp of when file has been changed the last time
clearstatcache();
$lastModified = filemtime($outputfile);

// if no timestamp delivered via ajax 
// or data.txt has been changed SINCE last ajax timestamp
if ($lastTimestamp == null || $lastModified > $lastTimestamp) {

    // get content of data.txt
    $data = file_get_contents($outputfile);

    // put data.txt's content and timestamp of 
    // last data.txt change into array
    $result = array(
        'data' => $data,
        'timestamp' => $lastTimestamp
    );

    // encode to JSON, render the result (for AJAX)
    $json = json_encode($result);

} else {

    // No updates in the file, just kick back the current time
    // and the client will check back later
    $result = array(
        'timestamp' => time()
    );

    $json = json_encode($result);
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo $json;
```

Then, in the browser, you just have a tiny client that polls for it's 'jobid' to check on status.

**client.js**

```
$(function () {

  var jobid = '12345';
  function checkForUpdates(timestamp) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost/server.php',
      data: {
        'timestamp': timestamp,
        'jobid': jobid
      },
      success: function (data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if (obj.data) {
          // Update status content
          $('#response').text(obj.data);
        }
        // Check again in a second
        setTimeout(function () {
          checkForUpdates(obj.timestamp);
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
  }

  checkForUpdates();
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Status:</h1>
        <div><pre id="response"></pre></div>
    </body>
</html>
```